# get camera from pythonanywhere for opencv with flask

Tags: opencv, flask, camera

I have a web application that recognizes faces through the camera, the web app works on the local server, the problem is when I upload it to pythonamywhere and it doesn't detect the camera

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

This is the code snippet in the index.py that

get the camera

I have seen that the camera is obtained with javascript, but how do I pass it to opencv using flask so that it recognizes the faces?